# How to place a breakpoint at the start of a method programmatically?

Tags: matlab, oop, debugging

In Matlab, when I want to run a function through the debugger, I can type `dbstop func`, which puts a breakpoint at the first code line in `func.m`.  Then, when I call `func(...)`, I can proceed through the function step by step.

Is there any equivalent for methods?  If I want to debug into an interactive call of `obj.meth()`, none of these alternatives work:

- `dbstep in` only works if the code to be stepped into is part of the function I'm debugging, not if I'm calling it interactively
- `dbstop obj.mymeth`, `dbstop MyClass/mymeth`, or `dbstop MyClass.mymeth` fail with `Cannot find function MyClass.mymeth`.
- So, perhaps it's treated like a subfunction. However, `dbstop in MyClass at mymeth` fails with `Cannot find function "mymeth" within "MyClass"`.  This one actually surprises me most.  Note that even if it would work, I would still need to find out the defining class first.
- `dbstop mymeth` actually *does* set a breakpoint, but it sets it at line 1 of `MyClass`, rather than at the beginning of `MyClass.mymeth`.  I have not tested what happens if `mymeth` is overloaded.
- Next, I tried it through the metaclass and metamethod: `ms = ?MyClass; meth = ms.MethodList(strcmp({ms.MethodList.Name}, 'mymeth'))`
  , gives me an `meta.method` object to my method.  However, `dbstop` wants a string, so I can't put a breakpoint.  And although the meta.method does tell me the defining class, it does not tell me the line number where the method is defined, so I can't set a breakpoint like this either.

Then, all that is left is to determine the defining class from the `meta.method`, open the corresponding file in the graphical interactive editor, search for the line defining the method, and put a breakpoint by hand.  This is time-consuming and only works when working graphicaly.

Is there any way to step into an interactively called method, or to programmatically set a breakpoint at the beginning of a method?  I'm using 2013a.

Comment: The second and third bullet points got really close.  I got it to work with minor modification as in my updated answer.  Hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following syntax worked for a simple test on my computer:

```
dbstop in MyClass.m at MyClass.mymeth
```

Comment: Indeed, but how did you know this??!